# css four-column left floated layout with equal left and right margins

Tags: css-float, margins, multiple-columns

I have a four-column, left-floated layout. I want equal margins for left and right margins.  I've floated the four columns to the left and assigned a right margin of 20px on each float.  The full width column div looks correct, but the margins and columns are not displaying correctly on the columns with different widths.  I've gone over the math several times and my eyes are burning trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Any suggestions on the best way to do this or how to do this?  I could create a 20px width first column for a total of five columns, or use tables.  But I was looking for a more elegant way of doing this, but maybe it's not possible.  I also have to support IE7.  Thanks.

[Code here - 4 column margins not correct](http://jsfiddle.net/Chris22/w3YRF/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem with your CSS is that you didn't take the padding into account.

In order to do this more elegant you should centred all the blocks with equals margins.

I've inspected your code and modified it a little :)

http://jsfiddle.net/w3YRF/5/

Anyway, I recommend you to use a Grid System such as Grid960 (http://960.gs/) that you give you a great hand on your way!

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, turik.  Yes, I've used the 960 and was going to resort to that, but it is not used in the rest of the code (tables are being used) so I kind of set up my columns in a "quasi" grid-like layout.  I figured it was the padding/margins incorrect, and been tweaking for awhile.  So many thanks for lending me your eyes and brain! :)

Comment: @ turik if you take a look at your solution you will notice the "gutters" in between the columns are wider (15+15)than than the left and right margins, that's not what I want. I want equal spacing between columns (20px) _including_ the left and right margin